# Wordpress MU LDAP connection failures

Tags: plugins, multisite, multisite-user-management

I'm using Wordpress 3.8.1,  WPMU Ldap Authentication plugin 4.0.2 ([This site fixes the deprecated WordPress functions](http://fotan.us/wpmu-ldap-plugin-fixes/) ), and [Linode Hosting](http://www.linode.com) with Linux CentOS 6 and I'm still having problems connecting LDAP. When I test the connection it takes a long time and comes back a "***Connection: Failed***". Is there a way to look at a LDAP Debug file so I can check for errors?

Answer (score 0):

I have my LDAP issues as well. Can you check and see if its not a firewall issue? Usually LDAP directories are behind firewalls and you need to make sure that the connection between your WP and the LDAP directory is open. Also check for if the ldap directory needs to be connected over SSL.

Comment: I do know it's over SSL and where using port 3269 has instructed by the plugin.

Comment: Try pinging your LDAP server from your Wordpress server. If it connects, you might have to use a different LDAP plugin.

Comment: Found the problem. The LDAP server for "Search User DN" needed a password in "Search User Password" and it needed a the address name of the server and not the IP address.  Some of the other plugins don't have a that option when I looked.